# error: request for member 'clear' in 'graph', which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define pii pair<int, int>

vector<pii> graph[100001];

int main() {
    graph.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: request for member 'clear' in 'graph', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > [100001]'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `graph` is *an array of 100001 vectors of pairs of ints*, not `std::vector<T>`.

You can however represent graphs like below:

```
#define pii std::pair<int, int>

std::vector<std::vector<pii> > graph(100001);

graph.clear();
```

If you **really really** want to use raw arrays, you can **very inefficiently** clear your `graph` like below:

```
std::fill_n(graph, 100001, std::vector<pii>());
```